# Ignore Prefix on the Homepage Page Title

Tags: kentico

I am setting up the page titles in my Kentico site. I was able to find the location to control the title structure across all pages but I do not want the homepage to follow that structure.

This is the structure I am using:
{%pagetitle_orelse_name%} | My Site Name Here

For the homepage, I do not want it to follow this structure. I have the "Inherit" boxes unchecked on the homepage and entered in the special title.

It is still coming up with the title I entered + "| My Site Name Here"

Any ideas?

Brian

Answer (score 0):

The Postfix is indeed because in the Setting, it's set that way.  You can remove the setting, but it will remove the postfix for the other pages as well.

It renders with a macro, so have you tried doing something like this in the setting?

```
{%pagetitle_orelse_name%} {% if(DocumentContext.CurrentDocument.NodeAliasPath != "/Home") { return " | My Site Name Here"; } @%}
```

Worth a shot, then it won't show the postfix for the home page.

Comment: Worked PERFECTLY. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

To fix this you can remove or clear that setting all together in the Settings app.  Then go to the Pages app and select your master page's Properties>Metadata.  In the page title box add something like this:

`{% if(CurrentDocument.NodeAliasPath.ToLower() != "/home") {"My Site Name"}else {DocumentName + " - My Site Name"} %}`

This will auto populate through the rest of the pages assuming you have left the inherit page title checkbox checked.  Keep in mind there is a bug in v10 before hotfix 4 that doesn't allow recursive macros, so if you're in v9, you're ok.  If you're in v10 before hotfix 4 you will need to apply at least hotfix 5 to see this work properly.